# Implementing Matrix Plotting in R Function

Tags: r, function, plot

The function below is a function that uses distributions to then fill a matrix up with values.

```
library(tidyverse)

occ_simulation <- function(nyears, lambda, alpha, beta){
  
  data_matrix <- matrix(, nrow = nyears, ncol = 6)
  
  for (z in 1:nyears){
    data_matrix[z][1] <- z
  }
  
  for (yr in 1:nyears){
    
    poisson_sim = rpois(1, lambda)
    
    for (number_of_events in poisson_sim){
      
      if (number_of_events == 1){
        
        beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
        data_matrix[yr, 2] <- beta_sim
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 2){
        
          for (i in 2:3){
            
            beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
            
          }
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 3){
          
          for (i in 2:4){
            
            beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
        
          }
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 4){
        
          for (i in 2:5){
            
            beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
        
          }
          
      } else{
        
          for (i in 2:6){
            
            beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
            data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
        }
    
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
  sorted_matrix <- cbind(data_matrix[,1],t(apply(data_matrix[,2:6],1,function(x) sort(x))))
  print(sorted_matrix)
  
}


manual = occ_simulation(10, 10, 2, 20)
```

For example, the output matrix of this function is:

```
      [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
 [1,]    1 0.083134569 0.08617405 0.09887510 0.11772536 0.22531132
 [2,]    2 0.031942297 0.05572298 0.13227172 0.13373033 0.18225673
 [3,]    3 0.034385791 0.05340521 0.06165728 0.08298166 0.09168579
 [4,]    4 0.051670957 0.08783456 0.10290313 0.11267966 0.14254834
 [5,]    5 0.005269822 0.01229135 0.03251302 0.03560609 0.12144208
 [6,]    6 0.059678131 0.06291472 0.07521237 0.08371512 0.17253282
 [7,]    7 0.020974306 0.03211666 0.03951780 0.12363214 0.12707027
 [8,]    8 0.066050034 0.09113262 0.11433074 0.11642412 0.19931177
 [9,]    9 0.042327058 0.08072802 0.15232605 0.17718338 0.19237172
[10,]   10 0.034537165 0.07571227 0.09081958 0.11202394 0.11799924
```

What I was wondering, was how will I be able to also implement plotting into my function so that I get the first column of the matrix as the values of the x axis and then the row of points plotted according to their x value being plotted on the y axis.

For example for an x value of 1, I will have 5 points plotted directly above it, those 5 points being the ones in the first row: `0.083134569, 0.08617405, 0.09887510, 0.11772536, 0.22531132`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach. Concatenate the plot sketch using `tidyverse` at the end of the function. When you apply it with some parameters, the plot will be stored in the object `manual`. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Function
occ_simulation <- function(nyears, lambda, alpha, beta){
  
  data_matrix <- matrix(, nrow = nyears, ncol = 6)
  
  for (z in 1:nyears){
    data_matrix[z][1] <- z
  }
  
  for (yr in 1:nyears){
    
    poisson_sim = rpois(1, lambda)
    
    for (number_of_events in poisson_sim){
      
      if (number_of_events == 1){
        
        beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
        data_matrix[yr, 2] <- beta_sim
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 2){
        
        for (i in 2:3){
          
          beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
          data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
          
        }
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 3){
        
        for (i in 2:4){
          
          beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
          data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
          
        }
        
      } else if (number_of_events == 4){
        
        for (i in 2:5){
          
          beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
          data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
          
        }
        
      } else{
        
        for (i in 2:6){
          
          beta_sim = rbeta(1, alpha, beta)
          data_matrix[yr, i] <- beta_sim
        }
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
  sorted_matrix <- cbind(data_matrix[,1],t(apply(data_matrix[,2:6],1,function(x) sort(x))))
  #Plot
  G <- sorted_matrix %>% as.data.frame %>%
    pivot_longer(-V1) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=factor(V1),y=value,color=name,group=name))+
    geom_point()+
    labs(color='Column',x='V1')+
    theme_bw()
  return(G)
}
#Apply
manual = occ_simulation(10, 10, 2, 20)
manual
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to instead return the plot instead of trying to plot it. Does the manual at the end of the code result in the program actually showing the plot instead then?

Comment: @Nhyi Yeah, it is a way to print the object. Otherwise it only will be stored in the object manual. I hope that was useful and helpful for you!

Comment: @Nhyi Let me know if my explanation was clear enough!

Comment: Yeah it was! I think before I was plotting it but it wasn't updating because I wasn't actually returning the object to print. It makes a lot more sense to do this than what I was doing previously!

Comment: Quick question regarding the plotting. How would I change the label for the key on the right hand side or is it possible to change it so the data points are numbered? So for one colour all the data points are labelled as 1 and then for the second colour it is 2 etc?

Comment: @Nhyi It is possible just add this to the pipeline in the plot after `pivot_longer()` add `mutate(name=gsub('V','',name)) %>%` then you would have different labels in the legend!